# Is it natural to use the verb "cause" for a good or neutral happening?

Tags: word-choice

I checked the word "cause" in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cause).

It says:

*"to make something happen, **especially something bad**"*

The examples provided:

> *The difficult driving conditions caused several accidents.*

> *[ + obj + to infinitive ] The bright light caused her to blink.*

> *Most heart attacks are caused by blood clots.*

> *[ + two objects ] I hope the children haven't caused you too much trouble."*

Since Cambridge Dictionary says "especially something bad", I wonder if it seems unnatural to natives if I use the verb cause for neutral or good happenings.

Can I also use the verb cause for neutral or good happening?

For example, can I say:

> 1. The support of my family caused me to succeed in my exams. (a good happening)

> 2. His behavior caused me to think. (a neutral happening)

Isn't it better, or does it make any difference, if I express the two above examples with the verb "make":

> 3. The support of my family made me be successful in my exams. (a good happening)

> 4. His behavior made me think. (a neutral happening)

Comment: Note that it says '_especially_ something bad', not that the word is _only_ used for bad results. Even so, I would suggest _helped_ in your Sentence 1.

Answer (score 2):

It would be odd to use "cause" in the exam context.

It would imply that you had no choice. You were made to pass the exam by your families support, and you couldn't have done anything different. The same problem exists with "the support of my family made me pass".  I'd use something like "The support of my family enabled me to pass."  (In formal logic the support of your family was a necessary, but not sufficient condition)

It is fine to use "cause" in situations (good or neutral) in which there is no choice:  "The warm spring sun causes the flowers to bloom."  If you think flowers are good, that is a positive outcome, but the flowers don't have any choice. The warm spring sun is sufficient for the flowers to bloom.

"His behaviour caused me to think." This fine.  His behaviour was a sufficient condition for you to think.

Comment: +1 To add that because it's common for "cause" to mean something negative, "*His behaviour caused me to think*" might suggest the thoughts were unwelcome ones, like self-doubt.